# How to insert the new line character into a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to insert a new line character between the name and address parts of a mailing label. Because it is a list of lists it will not let me enter a \n between the parts of the mailingLabelList.

```
def main():
    """ Open's file, reads customer information into a list, closes the file"""
    custFile = open('customerData.txt','r')
    mailingLabelFile = open('mailingLabels.txt','w')
    customerList = generateList(custFile)
    mailingLabelList = generateMailingLabel(customerList)
    mailingLabelFile.write("mailingLabels")
    mailingLabelFile.close()
    mailingLabelFile = open('mailingLabels.txt','r')

    # Echo first and last enter from the customerList
    print "customerList[0]:", customerList[0]
    print "customerList[-1]:",customerList[-1]

    print mailingLabelList[0]

    custFile.close()
    mailingLabelFile.close()

def generateList(custFile):
    """ Reads customer data from file and returns a list of customers"""
    customers = []
    for line in custFile:
        # Strip the new-line character from the end of the line, then split
        # the line on the commas (',') to get a list of customer fields
        custInfoList = line.strip().split(',')
        customers.append(custInfoList)
    return customers

def generateMailingLabel(customerList):
    """Reads customer data from custoemrList and sorts out the female customers in Iowa
    and creates a mailing label for those customers"""
    mailingLabelList = []
    for list in customerList:
        if list[5] == 'IA' and list[10] == 'female':
            mailingLabelList.append(list[0] + ' ' + list[2] + ' ' + list[3] + ' ' + list[4] + ' ' + list[5] + ' ' + list[6])
        return mailingLabelList

main()
```

Comment: Firstly, do not iterate over an iterable with the keyword **list**. Secondly, if you have a list of lists, why don't you just write a list comprehension to concatenate them into one string with a newline character at the end?

Comment: Please show us the actual error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
def generateMailingLabel(customerList):
    """Reads customer data from custoemrList and sorts out the female customers in Iowa
    and creates a mailing label for those customers"""
    mailingLabelList = []
    for list in customerList:
        if list[5] == 'IA' and list[10] == 'female':
            thing_to_append = ''.join(str(s) for s in list) + "\n"
            mailingLabelList.append(thing_to_append)
        return mailingLabelList
```